# Have a matplotlib button disconnect its own callback

Tags: python, matplotlib, callback

I would like to have a matplotlib button that can only be used once. Ideally, I could do this by disconnecting the callback. However, there is an issue of timing in having a callback disconnect itself.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Button

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
donebutton = Button(ax, "Disconnect the button")
def donecallback(event):
    donebutton.disconnect(donecid)
    print("Disconnected")

donecid = donebutton.on_clicked(donecallback)

plt.show()
```

To disconnect the callback, I need its callback ID, `donecid`, which I obtain when I connect the callback. To connect the callback, I first must define it, `donecallback`. To define the callback, I must already know the CID. Therefore, I am stuck with a chicken-and-egg problem.

There are workarounds, such as defining a class so that I can pass data into callbacks through `self`, having a global flag that keeps track of whether the button has been pressed, or creating a new, identical button with no callback connected. It would be nice, however, if there were a simpler way. Is there?

EDIT:
The following error occurs when I use either the code I gave. or the code provided by dnalow.

````
    func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\matplotlib\widgets.py", line 210, in _release
    for cid, func in self.observers.items():
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap a class around it:

```
class MyButton(Button):
    def on_clicked(self, func):
        self.cb_id = super(MyButton, self).on_clicked(func)
        return self.cb_id

    def disconnect(self):
        return super(MyButton, self).disconnect(self.cb_id)



donebutton = MyButton(ax, "Disconnect the button")
def donecallback(event):
    donebutton.disconnect()
    print("Disconnected")

donebutton.on_clicked(donecallback)
```

However, one might want to better handle the case where several events are defined. Also, you could rather define a class of Button that automatically disconnects after the first event?!

EDIT:

The above approach doesn't work. Instead, you can use the `active` attribute to deactivate the whole button. It does not disconnect from a certain callback function, so it is not really what you asked for.

Following your example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Button

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
donebutton = Button(ax, "Disconnect the button")
def donecallback(event):
    donebutton.active = False
    print("Disconnected")

donecid = donebutton.on_clicked(donecallback)

plt.show()
```

EDIT 2:

another approch by overriding the `_release` method of the Button:

```
class SingleUseButton(Button):
    def _release(self, event):
        if self.ignore(event):
            return
        if event.canvas.mouse_grabber != self.ax:
            return
        event.canvas.release_mouse(self.ax)
        if not self.eventson:
            return
        if event.inaxes != self.ax:
            return
        for cid in list(self.observers):
            func = self.observers.pop(cid)
            func(event)
```

Comment: Thank you - this is the first workaround I mentioned at the end of my answer. I was wondering if there were a way to do this without an auxiliary object, but this is probably the best solution available.

Comment: I just tried this, and it actually gives me the same error I was given when I tried doing things without defining a class: "RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration"

Comment: can you give the full traceback?

Comment: It makes sense that it doesn't work. The button connections are part of a dictionary. During iteration through all connections, the size of the dictionary must not change. So using disconnect as part of the event is not possible and your question remains unanswered

Comment: I added another approach. It deactivates the whole button. But there are other ways. You could override the `_release` method making a single-use-button for several callbacks.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions! Deactivating the button is interesting. If you'll forgive my inexperience, I don't know what you're talking about with the other suggestion, as the documentation https://matplotlib.org/3.2.2/api/widgets_api.html does not list a `_release` method.

Comment: You can find the definition of the `Button` class here: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/_modules/matplotlib/widgets.html#Button
If you define your own Button, inheriting from that one, you just need to override the _release method. Do you need an example?

Comment: I see what you are referring to now, and understand what you're saying as far as overriding the `_release` method by defining my own. Do you mean to add a piece of code to the existing `_release` code which removes the callback which was just called from the dictionary?

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was thinking of after your comment about overriding the method. You have helped me very much.